# url from database incomplete

Tags: php, mysql, url

I'm trying to make an url shortener and I solve many problem but there is two more problem at this moment like if domain.com/XXX redirect to amazon.com/abcéxyz it redirect me to amazon.com/abc so it's basically cut off at the first accented letter ?
my database is a mysql local database here is the [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAAdE.png)

The other problems is to redirect properly to an link because when I redirect to dofus.com here It gave me "CORS" [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5B0X.png) in Phpstorm so I need to know how to avoid that
thanks

```
<?php
$pdo = '';
require_once 'config.php';

function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max)
{
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
    $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd > $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
}

function getToken($length)
{
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited

    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0, $max-1)];
    }

    return $token;
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM url WHERE shortenurl=:id");
    $stmt->execute(['id' => $_GET["id"]]);
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header('Location:' .$data["primaryurl"], true, 302);
    exit();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Remy Barranco</title>
    <meta name="description" content="URL Shortener">
    <meta name="author" content="Rémy Barranco">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="form">
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="primaryurl" placeholder="Paste here your url" id="primaryurl" autocomplete="off" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Short"/>
</form>

</div>
<div id="shortened">
    <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $shortened = getToken(6);
        $url = [
            'primaryurl' => $_POST['primaryurl'],
            'shorturl' => $shortened

        ];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO url (primaryurl, shortenurl) VALUES (:primaryurl, :shorturl)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($url);
        unset($pdo);
        echo "your shorten url is ", $shortened;
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to hell. You can't specify an encoding for URLs, so you must urlencode anything that's not 7-bit safe. Sure your browser displays `é` in the URL bar and may or may not let you copy-paste it as such, but in the background it's sending `%C3%A9` to the server. But only if it thinks it is UTF-8. If it thinks it's ISO8859-1 or cp1252 it's sending `%E9`. There's no way to know exactly what your users have pasted in.

Comment: Also the hostname portion of the URL needs to be encoded [_wildly differently_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) if it contains UTF-8 which is, seemingly perplexingly, the de-facto encoding for IDNs.

Comment: so if I understand there's nothing I can do ??

Comment: There's plenty that you can do, but it's a _lot_ of work and will sometimes not function correctly. However, I'm a fan of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out), so if a user puts a malformed URL in, they get the same one out. Tack on a FAQ explaining why `http://日本語.jp/é` needs to be `http://xn--wgv71a119e.jp/%C3%A9` and suggest browsers like Chrome that copy/paste URLs in the correct format. Or simply put in a check that if the input contains a byte with an ordinal value above 127 kick back a warning/rejection to the user.

Comment: I'm beginner on php so I don't think i can do all the thing you say, however thank you for your answers

Comment: _“The other problems is to redirect properly to an link because when I redirect It gave me "CORS" error”_ - and where is the relevant code relating to that part of the problem? You have not even shown any client-side code that could cause such an error yet.

Comment: You could at least try to fix improperly encoded URLs (results may vary). `parse_url` and `parse_str` help you take the input value apart into its components, `idn_to_ascii` can fix un-encoded IDN host names, `rawurlencode` and `http_build_query` help with encoding the path segments and query string parameters … a _very crude(!)_ first attempt could look something like this, https://3v4l.org/9NFhT (that does not contain any checks whether all the URL parts are actually set yet.)

Comment: Of course this will only work under the assumption that the path component and query string contents are “in” UTF-8 - but submitting such an un-encoded URL via a browser address bar, will usually assume UTF-8 to be used these days as well.

Comment: I added the cors error description to the original post, the whole code is in the first post. Thanks for your exemple on which encoding can I use.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it work perfectly

```
function redirect($url){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>'; exit;}
```